# How to save or send the data entered on web page into a Microsoft Project(.mpp) file in java

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, ms-project

One of our clients requires a web application to be created with elements mapping to the columns of Microsoft Project (.mpp) file.

As soon as an employee/resource enters details about his task like start date, finish date, percentage completion and so on.., the data should be saved into a Microsoft project (.mpp) file.

I am just curious to know if this can be acheived using Java?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MPXJ project](http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/).

> This library provides a set of facilities to allow project information
>   to be manipulated in Java and .Net. MPXJ supports a range of data
>   formats: Microsoft Project Exchange (MPX), Microsoft Project
>   (MPP,MPT), Microsoft Project Data Interchange (MSPDI XML), Microsoft
>   Project Database (MPD), Planner (XML), Primavera (PM XML, XER, and
>   database), Asta Powerproject (PP, MDB), and the Standard Data Exchange
>   Format (SDEF).